# Numerical approximation to quantile function for Gamma distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution

I am building a stats/probability library in python and right now I am working on the properties of the gamma distribution. I know that its quantile function (F^-1(x)) does not have a nice closed-form solution, so I am trying to find a numerical method that gives a good approximation. As I'm using the gamma distribution for bayesian statistics, I'm using the rate parameterisation, in case that detail is useful.

Can anybody suggest a method with < 10^-6 error bounds?

PS: Is there a subfield of numerical methods specifically for statistics? I am struggling to find resources online.

PS2: I dug up an old algorithm that can approximate the quantiles of a chi-square function and then convert them to a gamma, but this gamma is parameterised with scale. I am not sure how to do convert it to a gamma parameterised w/ rate.

Comment: The scale parameter is the inverse of the rate parameter, so that should pose you no difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if one is simply interested in a quantile function, it can look it up through the CDF. And if you are working in Python, that is directly available through the [`scipy.special`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#module-scipy.special) module. It includes the Gamma distribution cumulative distribution function parametrised by the rate parameter under the function [`gdtr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gdtr.html#scipy.special.gdtr), the inverse of `gdtr` in respect to `x`, `a` (here denoting rate) and `b` (here denoting shape) are also available through the functions `gdtrix`, `gdtria` and `gdtrib` respectively.

If in need of something more specialised, one may want to check the functions [`gammainc()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html) and [`gammaincinv()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincinv.html) for the regularized lower incomplete gamma function and the inverse of it. So for example we have:

```
>>> gdtr(0.4, 3, 2.0) # rate, shape, x
0.047422596071490235
>>> gammainc(3, 2.0*0.4) # If it was scale we would divide.
0.047422596071490235
```

Regarding your side-question: The field you are inquiring about it not really Statistics but rather Numerical Analysis. The C++ Boost library (which effectively what scipy is following) has some references on [Incomplete Gamma Functions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/igamma.html)  if you wish to read this further. A first reference to look into would be Temme (1979) *[The Asymptotic Expansion of the Incomplete Gamma Functions](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0510071)* in SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis.